# Getting difference between 2 dates

Tags: ruby

I want to get the number of days, hours and minutes between two dates. How do I do this?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

```
d3=d1-d2
d3.days
d3.hours
d3.min
d3.sec
#etc...
```

**Note:** This is the answer to the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8927767/2), not to the different question it was edited into after the answer was posted.

However, as @dukedave mentioned in the comments, this isn't really a working answer. Please use @RealCasually's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12983870/1008938) below.

Comment: this code is not working for me. it is giving some integer number

Comment: The number of days *is* an integer.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, assuming `d1` and `d2` are some date-like class: The amount of time assigned to `d3` will a number of seconds as `Float`. Adding `.unit` means that number is interpreted as that many units, then converted back to seconds.
So `1.minutes` will return `60` (seconds), not the number of minutes in one second (which could be `1/60`).

Comment: @animatedgif: Haven't looked back at this answer for a while. This *was* the right answer for the original (nearly incomprehensible) question, but is now wrong. Should I delete it?

Answer (score 6):

I have not found a Ruby-ish seconds_to_hours function (although it's trivial to build), but there is an obvious solution at the bottom of this post.

```
s = Time.now
e = Time.now + 3.hours
d = e - s
 => 10803.318176
```

Note: This value is simply a float, representing the seconds between the two date values.

I would like that to return hours. To do so, you divide by the time, in seconds.

```
b = d / 1.hour.seconds
 => 3.0009217155555556
```

My goal was to get a decimal value of hours, rounded to the nearest 6 minutes, so:

```
r = b.round(1)
 => 3.0
```

To sum it all up:

```
r = ((e - s) / 1.hour.seconds).round(1)
 => 3.0
```

Comment: You don't actually need the `.seconds` on the end, incidentally.